# Script work on non logged in user but not work for logged in user?

Tags: plugin-development, jquery, wp-enqueue-script

I am currently working with jquery and wordpress plugin.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $('.btn').click(function(){
          alert("hello world");
    });
});
```

This code working very well when run on the site as a usual visitor(non logged in user), but it is refusing to work when I am logged in on that wordpress site.

Is there anything wrong in my code that could possibly make this problem happen?

After try to open my consol, I try to enter my code above and run it via console. and then try to click the button again, the code working. I dont understand why since my js file is there, included and printed in `wp_footer()` like this

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="....url..../mycode.js"></script>
```

that mean --if I'm not wrong -- my code is there, but the function

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    ......
});
```

not executed when document is ready. That is why when I try to run it via console, the program run just like when I am not logged in.

Any suggestions

Comment: Is there a chance you are doing an ajax call? if yes then you  need to use both the hooks. check [wordpress.org](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_ajax_(action)) for more details.

Comment: `jQuery(document).ready()` fails when a script is loaded async. The better approach to add a click handler is `jQuery.on('click','.btn',function(event){ /* do stuff */ })`.

Comment: @marutiMohanty> no, the script is just as simple as i posted. i am not doing any ajax call..

Comment: @jornLund > i am using the `jQuery(document)...` just to asign the $ witch i want to use this in my script late. say `$(this).text('button text changed to this after clicked');`

if i want to try your suggested approach, i just simply have to change the `jQuery(document).ready(function(){ /*my script */ });` to this `jQuery.on('click','.btn',function(event){ /* do stuff */ })`

Comment: flagging it to close as off-topic as it is not obvious how wwordpress might part of the problem here. What you need to do is to find the differences between the pages/js generated for logged-in and non logged-in user and edit your question with that info. Without it even if the question is on topic it is very hard to guess why you get such a behaviour.

Comment: Can you provide live example? There us nothing in code you quoted which would cause such behavior.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i finally know why this code not work.
as menstioned by Jorn Lund in the comment that

```
jQuery(document).ready()
```

will fail when script loaded async ( i still dont know is my code load async) but with in mind i change from

```
jQuery(document).ready()
```

to self execution function

```
(function($){
    alert("hello");
})(jQuery);
```

and the code work very well on both loggedin and non loggedin user.